# Taylor expansion on embedded Riemannian manifolds

Tags: taylor-expansion, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know if such a result is true:

Let $M$ be a Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$, $f:M \to \mathbb R$ a smooth function and $x_0 \in M$. Then we have
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+df(x_0)(v)+ d^2f(x_0)(v,v) + o(\| x-x_0\|^2),
$$
where $v$ is the orthogonal projection of $x-x_0$ on the tangent space $T_{x_0}M$.

Thanks !

Comment: what is $d^2$ to you? Because if you mean the exterior derivative, then $d^2 f = 0.$ It might make more sense to consider $v(v(f))$ or $\mathcal{L}_v^2 f.$ You might be interested in the Lie series expansion of a function.

Comment: $d^2f(x_0)$ is the Hessian of $f$ at $x_0$. It is well known that it is well defined for any smooth function $f: M \to \mathbb R$ where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: Understood, just clarifying. The notation $d^2$ isn't used in work I've seen to denote the Hessian so the notation wasn't clear.